# Accessing the 2D array in a Matrix class (C++) (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, matrix

I am a relatively new programming student and very new to C++ so please bear with me while I struggle to sort through this.

I am trying to make a Matrix class with a few basic functions to change it. Objects created in the Matrix class should be a 100x100 2D array of floats. I should be able to change a value at a particular location in this array to another value. The relevant code is as follows:

```
    //in the .h file
    class MatrixC
    {
    private:
       float matrix[100][100];

    public:
       void initializeMatrix(MatrixC);
       void printMatrix(MatrixC);
       void setValue(MatrixC, float, int row, int column);
       float getValue(MatrixC, int row, int column);
    }

   //in the .cpp file
   void setValue(MatrixC matrix, float value, int row, int column)
   {
      matrix[row][column] = value; //ERROR LINE
   }
```

I am getting the following error at the line indicated above, with the first bracket in the line highlighted: "MatrixC matrix - No operator '[]' matches these operands."

I also get this error regarding the "=" in the same line.

After some googling, I could not for the life of me figure out how to fix the issue regarding the 
"[]". The issue regarding the "=" seems to be because the compiler thinks that "matrix[row][column]" and "value" are different data types, but both are referring to floats. I suspect that this problem will be fixed once the problem with the "[]" is fixed.

Am I accessing the 2D array inside the MatrixC class improperly? If so, I have no idea how to do it properly. If not, I have no clue what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Matrix` object as an array, which he is not.
If you want to use the [] operator,
you should overload it.
More on overloading [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)

If you do not wish to overload the operator, you should create a function that returns your actual array member (or just make it public)
And than change the value.

By the way, I think that you might wanna change all the function signature for the matrix variable, and get a pointer to the object which will allow the actual change and not just a copy of the sent object.
Read more about references and pointers to understand.